# Combinatorial proof for ${m+n \choose m+r} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}{m \choose k}{n \choose r+k}$

Tags: combinatorics

$${m+n \choose m+r} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}{m \choose k}{n \choose r+k}$$
The problem makes sense to me, intutively, if I write out the left-hand side as: $${m\choose m}*{n \choose r}+{m\choose m-1}*{n \choose r+1}+...+{m\choose 1}*{n \choose r+m-1}+{m\choose 0}*{n \choose r+m}$$ 
You've introduced a group of size *m* to a group of size *n* and you have to pick *m* plus *r* in the first 'round', you simply pick every element from group *m* and get *m* elements, plus pick *r* elements from group *n*. Then the next time you don't pick one *m* and you pick an extra element from *n*, increasing in this way until you pick *m+r* elements from group *n*. The trouble is I have no idea how to write this out mathematically.

Please don't mark this as a duplicate of a post about Vandermonde's identity without explaining how this problem can be solved using Vandermonde's identity.

Comment: What  do the double parentheses mean in the second factor on the right of the sum?

Comment: ...what you've just described sounds like a bijection proof to me.  You could describe it in terms of colors of elements if you wanted to, but you've shown a way of counting a specific thing that yields the value on the left, and a different way of counting that thing that yields the value on the right.